# error to convert .ipynb and save it as pdf

Tags: pdf, python

I have converted many times the .ipynb jupyter notebook into `pdf`
but now suddenly I'm facing the error as below, any hints how to fix it are welcome.

```
Jupyter Notebook
500 : Internal Server Error

The error was:

nbconvert failed: PDF creating failed, captured latex output:
Failed to run "xelatex notebook.tex -quiet" command:
This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999995 (TeX Live 2023) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./notebook.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-06-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-10-10>
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size11.clo))
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.sty
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.
tex)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.d
ef)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/pgf.revision.tex)))
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/xetex.def)))
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.t
ex
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.te
x
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeyslibraryf
iltered.code.tex))
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-xetex.
def
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-dvipdf
mx.def
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common
-pdf.def))))
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpat
h.code.tex)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotoco
l.code.tex)) (d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/mathcolor.ltx))
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.t
ex (d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex
)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.t
ex)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.cod
e.tex)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.bas
ic.code.tex)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.tri
gonometric.code.tex)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.ran
dom.code.tex)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.com
parison.code.tex)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.bas
e.code.tex)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.rou
nd.code.tex)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.mis
c.code.tex)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.int
egerarithmetics.code.tex)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex
)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.te
x)) (d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfint.code.tex)

(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.
code.tex)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathcon
struct.code.tex)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusa
ge.code.tex)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.
code.tex)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphic
state.code.tex)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransfo
rmations.code.tex)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.c
ode.tex)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects
.code.tex)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathpro
cessing.code.tex)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.
code.tex)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.c
ode.tex)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.c
ode.tex)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexterna
l.code.tex)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.
code.tex)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretranspa
rency.code.tex)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepattern
s.code.tex)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorerdf.cod
e.tex)))
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.c
ode.tex)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.cod
e.tex)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-versi
on-0-65.sty)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-versi
on-1-18.sty))
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/verbatim.sty)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/environ/environ.sty
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/trimspaces/trimspaces.sty))
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tcolorbox/tcbbreakable.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcbbreakable.code.tex' version '6.1.0'
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdfcol/pdfcol.sty
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty))))
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/parskip/parskip.sty
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty)))
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-xetex.def))
) (d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-xetex.sty
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)))
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption.sty
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption3.sty))
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/float/float.sty)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/enumerate.sty)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifvtex.sty))
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty))
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/textcomp.sty)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/upquote/upquote.sty)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/eurosym/eurosym.sty)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ucs/ucs.sty
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ucs/data/uni-global.def))
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancyvrb/fancyvrb.sty)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/grffile/grffile.sty)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/adjustbox/adjustbox.sty
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex)))
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/adjustbox/adjcalc.sty)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/adjustbox/trimclip.sty
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/collectbox/collectbox.sty)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/adjustbox/tc-xetex.def))
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ifoddpage/ifoddpage.sty)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/varwidth/varwidth.sty))
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvdefinekeys/kvdefinekeys.sty
) (d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdfescape/pdfescape.sty)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hycolor/hycolor.sty)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/letltxmacro/letltxmacro.sty)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/auxhook/auxhook.sty)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/refcount/refcount.sty)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/gettitlestring/gettitlestring
.sty)) (d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/intcalc/intcalc.sty)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/puenc.def)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bitset/bitset.sty
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bigintcalc/bigintcalc.sty))
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atbegshi-ltx.sty))
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hxetex.def
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/stringenc/stringenc.sty)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/rerunfilecheck/rerunfilecheck.s
ty (d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atveryend-ltx.sty)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/uniquecounter/uniquecounter.s
ty))) (d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/titling/titling.sty)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/longtable.sty)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/booktabs/booktabs.sty)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/enumitem/enumitem.sty)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ulem/ulem.sty)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/jknapltx/mathrsfs.sty)
No file notebook.aux.
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/ltcaption.sty)
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: xetex
*geometry* verbose mode - [ preamble ] result:
* driver: xetex
* paper: <default>
* layout: <same size as paper>
* layoutoffset:(h,v)=(0.0pt,0.0pt)
* modes: 
* h-part:(L,W,R)=(72.26999pt, 469.75502pt, 72.26999pt)
* v-part:(T,H,B)=(72.26999pt, 650.43001pt, 72.26999pt)
* \paperwidth=614.295pt
* \paperheight=794.96999pt
* \textwidth=469.75502pt
* \textheight=650.43001pt
* \oddsidemargin=0.0pt
* \evensidemargin=0.0pt
* \topmargin=-37.0pt
* \headheight=12.0pt
* \headsep=25.0pt
* \topskip=11.0pt
* \footskip=30.0pt
* \marginparwidth=59.0pt
* \marginparsep=10.0pt
* \columnsep=10.0pt
* \skip\footins=10.0pt plus 4.0pt minus 2.0pt
* \hoffset=0.0pt
* \voffset=0.0pt
* \mag=1000
* \@twocolumnfalse
* \@twosidefalse
* \@mparswitchfalse
* \@reversemarginfalse
* (1in=72.27pt=25.4mm, 1cm=28.453pt)

(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ucs/ucsencs.def)

Package hyperref Warning: Rerun to get /PageLabels entry.

(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/jknapltx/ursfs.fd)

LaTeX Warning: No \author given.


Overfull \hbox (98.53447pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 436--436
[]\TU/lmtt/m/n/10.95 period1=1437747200&period2=441695513600&interval=1d&events
=history&includeAdjustedClose=true[][]"[], [] 

Overfull \hbox (98.53447pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 437--437
[]\TU/lmtt/m/n/10.95 period1=1437747200&period2=441695513600&interval=1d&events
=history&includeAdjustedClose=true[][]"[], [] 

Overfull \hbox (87.03691pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 438--438
[]\TU/lmtt/m/n/10.95 period1=1664045825&period2=1695581825&interval=1d&events=h
istory&includeAdjustedClose=true[][]"[], [] 
! Undefined control sequence.
\HyPsd@expand@utfvii ... {~{####1}}}\UTFviii@loop 
                                                  \count@ "E0 \@tempcnta "F0...
l.646 \end{tcolorbox}
                     
? 
! Emergency stop.
\HyPsd@expand@utfvii ... {~{####1}}}\UTFviii@loop 
                                                  \count@ "E0 \@tempcnta "F0...
l.646 \end{tcolorbox}
                     
No pages of output.
Transcript written on notebook.log.
```

Comment: do not load the ucs package.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer How can I do that (not to load it) ? What is and  `ucs` package ? I'm running Anaconda prompt and `Jupyter Notebook` and from it I wanted to save the page as `pdf` in my FF Mozilla.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I have renamed `ucs` with `ucs2` but I'm now getting this error: `! LaTeX Error: File `ucs.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name: 
! Emergency stop.
<read *> 
         
l.41     \usepackage
                    {fancyvrb} % verbatim replacement that allows latex^^M`

Comment: sorry I have no idea how you can change your document. I only know that loading ucs is wrong with xetex and is the cause of the error.

Comment: there is now a new ucs version in texlive which will not error with xelatex.